# Finding probability

Tags: probability, self-study, binomial-distribution

*Suppose it is known that in a certain population 10 percent of the population is color blind. If a random sample of 25 people is drawn from this population, find the probability that 5 or fewer will be color blind.

In solving this problem, what is the significance of the "10 percent"?

Comment: Please add a `[self-study]` tag and tell us what is your understanding of the problem and where are you stuck?

Comment: Actually, I think I've solved this without considering the "10 percent". In R, I used the code `pbinom(q=5,size=25,prob=.5,lower.tail = T)` which gave me 0.002038658. So I just wanted to be sure whether my answer is correct without counting the "10 percent" in my calculation.

Comment: How did you arrive to this code? (No, it is not correct.) Please edit your question.

Comment: The upper limit is 5, so `q=5` and `lower.tail=T`. A single individual is either color blind or not, so `prob=.5`.

Comment: Are you sure about 0.5 probability? If you draw a sample from a general population and check if individuals are >200 years old, or not, then would the probability be also 0.5 because you could either be >200 y.o. or not?

Comment: Okay, I get it. So should I use 0.1 or 0.1*0.5 or what?

Comment: Why *0.5 ? I answered below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a population with color blind and non-color blind people. What follows, if you randomly sampled a single person from this population, the probability that you sampled a color-blind person would be $0.1$ (since $10\%$ of the population is color blind), this would be a single [Bernoulli trial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution). If you drew a random sample of size $n$ from this population, then we would be talking $n$ Bernoulli trials, i.e. about [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) with sample size $n$ and probability of "success" $p=0.1$.